# Extraer caracteres con metodo substring en java

Tags: java, substring

pido una ayuda por favor; necesito extraer dos posiciones diferentes de una misma cadena con el metodo substring() de java, pero me genera error.

```js
package Entradas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejer20_parqueadero 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        double horaEntrada, horaSalida;
        String entrada="",salida="";
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese hora militar: ");
        Scanner hora=new Scanner(System.in);
               
        entrada=hora.nextLine().substring(0,2);
        salida=hora.nextLine().substring(3,5);
        
        
        System.out.println("entrada: "+entrada+" salida: "+salida);  
    }    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este error genera, cuando compilo

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa compila correctamente pero el código es incorrecto ya que realizas dos veces la lectura de línea (nextline), para ello debes guardar la hora introducida en una variable y posteriormente utilizar el substring 2 veces para obtener los valores que deseas.

Para que todo vaya bien tienes que hacer las siguientes modificaciones:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double horaEntrada, horaSalida;
        String entrada="",salida="";

        System.out.println("Ingrese hora militar: ");
        Scanner hora=new Scanner(System.in);

        String horaMilitar=hora.nextLine();
        entrada=horaMilitar.substring(0,2);
        salida=horaMilitar.substring(3,5);


        System.out.println("entrada: "+entrada+" salida: "+salida);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

en la imagen que muestras sucede que no has ingresado el valor para tu variable salida por eso te sale el error. Ahora, no entiendo muy bien lo que trates de lograr pero, tu programa si corre. Tienes que tomar en cuenta que cuando ingreses 22:12 al dar enter tienes que ingresar otro valor por ejemplo 23:11

La salida que arrojaría sería:

```
entrada: 22
salida: 11
```

Comment: Si correcto tienes razon. Lo que trato de lograr es obtener las hora y los minutos de una cualquier hora ingresada.

Answer (score 0):

Hola el problema esta acá:

```
entrada=hora.nextLine().substring(0,2);
salida=hora.nextLine().substring(3,5);
```

Al ejecutar `hora.nextLine()` por primer vez, obtienes "22:11", pero al ejecutarlo nuevamente, no vas a obtener ningun `String` porque no hay nada en la siguiente linea. Para solucionar el problema deberias guardar el valor en una variable `String` y luego aplicarle el substring a esta variable.

```
String input = hora.nextLine();
entrada = input.substring(0,2);
salida = input.substring(3,5);
```